# How to set the default plugin for a module in require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using require.js to load some JS libraries and want to run some common code before and after load. I have made a simple loader plug-in named `plug.js` to do so:

```js
define([], function () {
    return {
        load: function (name, req, onload, config) {

            // Pre-load code...

            req([name], function (value) {
                // Post-load code...

                onload(value);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When I use it from other modules like this, it works as expected:

```js
define(['plug!lib1'], function (lib1) {
    // Use lib1
}
```

But I want to prevent the library to be accidentally loaded with the default loader, so I tried to add the following mapping:

```js
require.config({
    // ...
    map: {
        '*': {
            'lib1': 'plug!lib1'
        }
    },
    // ...
}
```

Then I required the library in my modules without specifying the plug-in by `define(['lib1'], ...)` and the pre-load code of the plug-in runs as expected, but the post-load code never runs and I get load timeout errors. I also tried to apply mapping to specific modules rather than to `*`, but got the same error.

Is it something wrong with my loader plug-in code? Is it ever possible to have the default loader plug-in associated with a module (a global plug-in would also be acceptable)?

As an alternative I see making custom modules with pre-load code and setting them as dependencies in shim configuration, but this looks even less convenient than specifying the plug-in name everywhere.

Comment: Did you check whether this results in an infinite loop? I could imagine the plugin asking for `lib1`, which goes through the `map`, which requires the plugin to load `lib1`, etc.

Comment: @Louis Yes, I did. The pre-load code executes only once. Also note my try to apply a mapping to a specific module which depends on `lib1`. In this case I see no reasons for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like require.js tries to prevent circular dependency. `app` module requests `lib1`, which resolves to `plug!lib1`, and `plug` requests `lib1` again, which require.js refuses to load despite that this time it would be loaded directly rather than `plug` would be called recursively.

I renamed the original library, and the problem gone away:

```
require.config({
    // ...
    paths: {
        'lib1-core': 'lib1'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'lib1': 'plug!lib1-core'
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```